# Convert header-only library to modules

Tags: c++, makefile, c++-modules

I have a header-only (templated code) library, that I want to convert to use of modules.
The primary compiler will be gcc (13/14).

There are a couple of questions:

- What filename-extension should I use (.cxx)?
- What tools exist to generate the list of used libary-modules of a consuming-source-file in order to precompile these library files (using plain make) - or - ...
- ... should I precompile every library-file in advance?
- How can gcc find the precompiled library-files outside the local directory?

Comment: Use `.cpp` or `.cxx` for C++, and `.c` for C. The Makeflie can compile the modules that have changed, leaving the others alone.

Comment: You should put the main interface in `library.h` and each internal module in its own `.c` or `.cpp`. I'm not sure what you mean by "outside the local directory"... If your code depends on an external library, use `pkg-config` or similar to link it.